# Using wildcard to find similar values between two fields with ArcPy cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, query

I am using ArcMap 10.8. I have joined two street tables and am trying to correlate a couple fields. One field has a full street description ("FullStreet") and the other simply has the street name ("StreetName"). For quality assurance purposes, I have made a flagging field ('Flag'); the goal is to populate this field with "mismatch" in the case of completely different values, and "close" in the case the StreetName value is contained within FullStreet.

For example:

| FullStreet | StreetName | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N WEMBERLY LN | WEMBERLY | CLOSE |
| N WEMBERLY LN | YOCUM | MISMATCH |

I started with field calculator, but soon learned that wildcards are not supported, so I am trying to write a code with Python (v3.7). I think I am close, but am still having trouble incorporating the wildcard aspect:

```
streets = ("C:/.../Streets_M21.shp")


p_full = str('PSTR_FULNA')
my_full = str('FullStreet')
streetname = str('StreetName')
flag = str('Flag')
t_street = ( '%' + (streetname) + '%' )
fields = [p_full, my_full, t_street, flag]



with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(streets, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == row[1]:
            row[3] = "match"
        elif row[0] in row[2] and row[3] != "match":
            row[3] = "close"
        else:
            row[3] = "mismatch"
        
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

When run, this generates the an error: `RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.`

This must be referring to t_street, the wildcard attempt. I have also tried (*) as the wildcard operator, but when run, I get `Cannot find field '*StreetName*'`

How can I write this code so if the value in StreetName is anywhere within FullStreet, they will correlate?

Comment: Since you're using `elif` you don't need to test if the line above matched with `and row[3] != "match"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you CAN do a wild card search of your data with a select by attribute tool, I created a short [blog](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-blog/sql-expression-casting-concatenating-and-searching-within/ba-p/901890) over on ESRI Geonet which you should read.

In your case the expression would be:

```
FullStreet LIKE  '%' || StreetName || '%'
```

So with no code, you could easily select your matching rows and set your flag field to CLOSE and then invert the selection as all else are MISMATCH. This approach will take but a few seconds if you have a few thousand rows.

If you want to continue the python route then the query you want to test is simply:

```
if row[0] in row[1]:
    row[3] = "match"
```

So if row[0] was "cow" and row[1] was "cow lane" then you are asking if "cow" is in "cow lane" which is True.

Comment: Python supports similarity functions that would allow "Smyth St." and "Smith Street" to be scored as "close". There's a whole domain in Computer Science that studies this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also compare string similarity using [difflib.SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import arcpy

def similar(a, b):
    if all((a,b)):
        score = round(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio(), 2)
        if score>=0.5:
            flag = 'SIMILAR'
        else:
            flag = 'MISMATCH'
        return score, flag
    else:
        return (0.0, 'MISMATCH')


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(streets, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        SCORE, FLAG = similar(row[0], row[1])
        row[2] = FLAG
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]